# Maximizing memory usage

Tags: c++, memory-management, windows-xp

Is their any program in C++ which can maximize the memory usage until it reaches 'memory dump'(a blue screen and then restart). Just curious, to do this on windows xp.
What does it required?
Does an unlimited loop with multiplication or addition can maximize memory usage? I think no. It just increase CPU usage(but sadly not upto 10-20%). Then whats the way?

Answer (score 1):

Memory is used when you allocate variables. The fastest way would be to either allocate a really large array upfront or use `new` or `malloc` inside a loop:

```
while (true)
{
    new int[10000];
}
```

this will eventually throw an exception when you run out of memory.

Comment: At least on 32 bit windows because of address space fragmentation it may be difficult to allocate a single block of > ~1.2 GB. Although smaller blocks totaling almost 2GB will succeed.

Comment: Writing to some of those locations will probably work quicker.  Modern OS's don't bother allocating physical pages until data is written to thew virtual memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you've look to eat up all the available memory then just do this:

```
int main()
{
  while(true)
  {
    char *buffer=new char[1024];
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This will eat up memory in 1K chunks. However, all this will do is cause all the virtual memory available to your process, (around 2GB on 32 bit Windows) to be consumed, at which point your program will fall over and die without affecting anyone else.

If you're looking to write something that will cause Windows to fall over when it runs out of memory then you'll need to run your code in kernel space, so you'd need to write something like a device driver.